# error: Selection is not within a valid module

Tags: eclipse, glassfish

when i try to run my jsp files in eclipse bundle with glass fish, this error prompt out, what is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in [this thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.webtools/msg13977.html), this could be relate to [**bug 154833**](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=154833):

> > The current handling of project modules is such that the project name must match the deploy-name in the **`.settings/org.eclipse.wst.common.component`** for "everything" to work correctly.
> >     If they don't match, I believe the symptom you are experiencing is one of the "things" that goes wrong.
>
> That's it.
>   I was able to work around this problem by checking out the shared project into a project with the identical name as the original.
>   I no longer get the error

Answer (score 3):

today; this error wasted my time among 10 hours...
Its just because of Dynamic web module version 6.0 !!!
change that to 5.0

press file > new > Dynamic Web project > in that page change Dynamic web module version to 5.0 > next > finish

then create jar file and be ready to work

Comment: tutorial for anyone [change version of project facet Dynamic Web Module](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18361713/4573839)

Answer (score 1):

change Dynamic web module version 6.0 to 5.0 . It works fine.

Comment: Another answer already said this.... https://stackoverflow.com/a/75922639/362536

Answer (score 1):

To run the JSP file which shows this error **"the selection is not within a valid module"**
step 1: right click to your project

Step 2: Go to properties

Step 3: search project Facets click on that then

step 4: you can see Dynamic Web Module 6.0 ---> change it to 5.0 Then your problem will resolved

Answer (score 0):

I am creating Dynamic web project for first time but same error also there.

My issue was resolved when i followed these steps:

1. Connect tomcat with eclipse.
2. Create new Dynamic web project. When creating new project, select "target runtime" as "<none>", and "Configuration" as "Default Configuration".
3. After creating project, right click on project, select "Run as" > "Run on server" .
4. You will able to see a pop up window like this:
   [click to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wofBx.png)

5. Select the server and click finish.

Answer (score 0):

step 1:  right click to your project

Step 2: Go to **properties**

Step 3: search **project Facets** click on that then

step 4: you can see **Dynamic Web Module** 6.0 ---> change it to 5.0
Then your problem will resolved