# Tomcat starts but home page cannot open with url http://localhost:8080

Tags: java, tomcat

I am a newbie in Java, and I am trying to develop a web application. 
I have Windows 7 32 bit. I have installed Java 7 and set the path and classpath as well. After that I installed Tomcat 7.

When I try to open tomcat home page using URL `localhost:8080`, it does not open and Tomcat stops automatically.

Please help me.

Comment: Is there any error in tomcat console?

Comment: Can you paste the logs here ?

Comment: Can you check the tomcat logs to see if tomcat encountered any error? It'd be under <TOMCAT_DIR>/logs. Please check catalina.out and localhost log files for any exception. And if there is, post them here.

Comment: One place to check would be the log files for Tomcat. You should be able to find them in your /{TomcatDirectory}/logs/. Check the catalina.out file, it can sometimes give you some insight.

Comment: SEVERE: StandardServer.await: create[localhost:8005]: 
java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: JVM_Bind

Comment: @user3177634- i thing some other application using same port. Check my answer below. It contain solution

Comment: A Paul :- I am newbie..I dont know tomcat console.but when I enter http://localhost:8080 in browser tomcat homepage do not open

Comment: SEVERE: StandardServer.await: create[localhost:8005]: 
java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: JVM_Bind
 at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.bind0(Native Method)
 at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>

Comment: Which OS are you using ?

Comment: I am using windows 7 32 bit

Comment: I came into the same error. But I change the url into 127.0.0.1:8080 and it worked. However, I don't know try..

Answer (score 19):

Make sure no other application using port 8080 before starting tomcat. If that's not the problem please paste tomcat log.

If you want to change tomcat's default port, go to tomcat folder and open `conf` folder, in which  you can see `server.xml`. In that file you can see something like `<Connector port=` . Change the port value and start tomcat.

Comment: how can I check if other application is using port 8080 ?

Comment: To check if an other application is using port 8080, you can use TCPview. See on the followig link http://supportlife.wordpress.com/2011/03/18/tcpview-identify-and-close-open-connections-on-your-windows-machine/

Comment: Why can't you edit the server.xml? that's not a reasonable constraint

Comment: I am using windows 7 32 bit

Comment: because it was located in Windows drive. You just copy your conf file into you desktop. Now edit. Then relocate to same position.

Comment: @AniketJoshi "how can I check if other application is using port 8080 ?" open cmd.EXE as Administrator and type `netstat -ab`, press Enter.  You will see all the ports being used and what if anything is listening.

Comment: Tomcat wouldn't start if another port is using 8080.  There would be a bind error...so, this can't really be the answer given the OPs question....though this is often the answer if someone can't start tomcat as they've left a process running accidentally or something.

Answer (score 15):

If you started tomcat through eclipse, It can be solved in different ways too.

Method 1:

1. Right click on server --> Properties
2. click on Switch location and apply.

[image]

[image]
Method2:

1. Double click in the server in eclipse.
2. Change Server location to Use tomcat installation(takes control of tomcat installation).

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thanks. I do have a question though...I had to do both of the steps? I wonder if both are needed...

Comment: No... Following one method is fine.

Answer (score 9):

Your issue is not with port `8080`, but with port `8005`. Port `8005` is the shutdown port for Tomcat.

Rather than trying to figure out what is using port `8005`, it may just be easier to edit `TOMCAT_DIR/conf/server.xml` and change the shutdown port to `8006`

```
<Server port="8006" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
```

Comment: thanks for your reply.I am trying to edit that server.xml but I can't save.Can you please tell me how to edit that file.thank you.

Comment: You may find that the file needs administrator permissions to edit. Right-click your editor (notepad.exe - or whatever) and select 'Run as Administrator'. Then File > Open > server.xml

Comment: This worked for me! Thanks. @WillKeeling , why did we have to change the shutdown port?

Comment: This is a resolution if you get the error "SEVERE: StandardServer.await: create[localhost:8005]: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: JVM_Bind" as mentioned in the comments of the original post.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using eclipse to start the server then check for the server location being used and the deployment path:

[image: tomcat server location and deploy path]

In my case changing this to `Tomcat installation` instead of `workspace metadata` worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

For *Unix based systems, you can check the ports used by a particular application by issueing the following command in the terminal

```
[~/.]$ netstat -tuplen
```

You will get the list of all the ports that are being currently held and used by their respective process ID's

Comment: I am using windows 7 32 bit

Answer (score 2):

For  windows user, type `netstat -an`in command prompt to see ports that are listening, this may come handy.

Answer (score 2):

1) Using Terminal (On Linux), go to the apache-tomcat-directory/bin folder.

2) Type `./catalina.sh start`

3) To stop Tomcat, type `./catalina.sh stop` from the **bin** folder. For some reason `./startup.sh` doesn't work sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

For mac users

First Try : go to activity monitor -> search for java and kill the instance then restart the server and try.

Second Try:
Check log file for any errors under tomcat logs folder.

Use below command to check tomcat logs in terminal

```
tail -f {tomcatpath}/logs/catalina.out
```

Third Try:
Check if node or other apps using the same port. Use below command to check which app listening to a specific port. You will see list of apps with pid in second column.

```
lsof -i :8080 | grep LISTEN
```

Kill the process using below command

```
sudo kill -9 pid
```

Answer (score 0):

My issue has solved.I was getting log as below.

SEVERE: StandardServer.await: create[localhost:8005]:
java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: JVM_Bind

My tomcat server was automatically stopping when I tried to open tomcat homepage with
URL.

So I just made some changes in windows->System32->drivers->etc->host file.
keep only 127.0.0.1 localhost and remove all other. your problem will be solved.
Thank you guys for your help :D

Answer (score 0):

If you have your tomcat started (in linux check with `ps -ef | grep java`) and you see it opened the port 8080 or the one you configured in server.xml (check with `netstat --tcp -na | grep <port number>`) but you still cannot access it in your browser check the following:

1. It may start but with a delay of 3-5 minutes. Check the `logs/catalina.out`. You should see something like this when the server started completely.

   `INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 38442 ms`
   If you don't have this INFO line your server startup is not complete yet. The problem may occur due to the `SecureRandom` class responsible to provide random Session IDs and which can cause big delays during startup.
   Check more details and the solution [here](https://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/HowTo/FasterStartUp#Entropy_Source).
2. Check your firewall (on linux `iptables -L -n`): You can try to reset your firewall completely `iptables -F` if you are not into an exposed environment. However, pay attention, that leaves you without protection therefore it can be dangerous.
3. Check your `selinux` (if you are on linux).

These are some of the most forgotten and not obvious issues in having your Apache Tomcat up and running.

Answer (score 0):

I am using `Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers. Version: Oxygen.1a Release (4.7.1a) in Windows 8.1 x64` with `Apache Tomcat 8.5.24` (for testing purpose).

Port Name & Numbers for my Tomcat Server are :

```
Tomcat admin port   :   8005
HTTP/1.1            :   8081 (my Tomcat Listening Port Number)
AJP/1.3             :   8009
```

Peoples, for those the Tomcat were running good earlier, and **`sometimes`** sudden after `stopping tomcat server` explicitly by pressing the below shown image button or may be other reasons.

[image: Stopping Tomcat Server through Eclipse Standard Toolbar button explicitly]

**`Either`** they continuously failed to `start/restart` the tomcat with below said error:

> **Server Tomcat vX.Y Server at localhost failed to start.**

**`or`** sometimes the **`Tomcat Server is started`** but instead of showing **`Tomcat Homepage`** in web browser, it is throwing client exception **`HTTP Status 404 – Not Found.`** in preferred web browser.

possibly, there are many reasons i.e. wrong `Host name` defined, Wrong Tomcat `Server Locations` defined in eclipse, project `JDK/JRE` version mismatch with `Tomcat JRE dependent version`, maven project version mismatch due to `maven.compiler.source` and `maven.compiler.target` version not defined under properties tag, [mismatch version of project facet Dynamic Web Module to 2.5/3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18122336/cannot-change-version-of-project-facet-dynamic-web-module-to-3-0), Sometimes Tomcat Server is running on Windows Services level, previous stopped Tomcat port number were still listening and the `processing pid` were not killed in Tomcat defined timespan **`Timeouts Stop (in seconds): 15(by default)`** in eclipse and `pid` still running, failed to start in defined **`Start (in seconds): XX`**, etc.

Here I will give the resolution on, how to check and kill the running existing Tomcat port number's `processing pid`(beware, you must be aware with after effects).

In Windows, open you command prompt, and follow steps(my tomcat HTTP port is 8081):

```
netstat -ano | findstr :8081
TCP    0.0.0.0:8081           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       2284
TCP    [::]:8081              [::]:0                 LISTENING       2284
```

if any listening is being there, above command will list details of port listening along with `processing pid` at last of the line(here pid is 2284).

now kill the running pid like:

```
taskkill /PID 2284 /F
SUCCESS: The process with PID 2284 has been terminated.
```

also illustrated the above two steps like following:

[image: Killing running PID]

Now, after resolving above illustrated reason, start the **`Tomcat Server`**.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. My tomcat was started but I was getting HTTP 404 page not found.However, in my situation, I installed tree instances of tomcat. Each instance contains conf, temp, work, webapps and logs folders. Unless I forgot, to copy the global web.xml under conf folder of each tomcat.

```
    e.g: /opt/tomcat/mytomcatInstance/conf/web.xml
```

The web.xml Deployment Descriptor file describes how to deploy a web application in a servlet container.

So even if my tomcat was up, my web apps could not be deployed properly.

Answer (score 0):

The problems may happen because of memory issue.
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

please verify the logfile, any issues related to hardware(memory).

Answer (score 0):

Look in TomcatDirectory/logs/catalina.out for the logs. If the logs are too long, delete the catalina.out file and rerun the app.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the port that tomcat was running on was defined in an application.properties file for 8000, not 8080. In my case, it looked like the same problem described here. Just leaving this here in case anyone has a similar setup and issue! :)