# Set Up New Tomcat Server

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I am kind of a newbie on server, environment stuff, so I need help on setting up a new Tomcat server.

Actually I have installed one instance and it is running already on my dedicated server, but I can't access it's main page, so it is made possible to deploy my apps.

[image]

These are the internet proccess in the server. Tomcat is running on port 8080. I tried to access it by IP:8080 and it doesn't work

So is there some extra configuration on a dedicated server to be made? Some security stuff?

Comment: If you can't hit the welcome page, with no apps deployed on it, then there could very well be a problem starting up.  The first thing to check is the `logs` folder under your Tomcat installation.  Check all the logs, and look for errors.  My guess is that you'll find something.

Comment: How is this programming-related? This question seems more suitable for [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21021136/tomcat-starts-but-home-page-cannot-open-with-url-http-localhost8080,
check logs for more info  - .../apache-tomcat-xx\logs ,view catalina.out and localhost access files

Comment: Try to **restart** the service: `service tomcat8 restart`, if this it doesn't work test to change the port, maybe it could this is the problem [Change Tomcat Port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18415578/how-to-change-tomcat-port-number)

Comment: Hello there. I tried to change port to 8090 and shutdown port to 8006, but anyways the problem keeps the same. To further information this has already one instance of a php app running on port 80. Maybe there is some dificulties from that? Also there may be some security check that is stopping me?

Comment: Also I restarted the service.

Comment: On the log files there isn't any problem. Only logs saying about server startup succesfully.

Comment: You can see on the users column that the user from tomcat is different from others. I followed as is descripted in this tutorial https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-8-on-centos-7 where i create a group named tomcat

Comment: Perfect, the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21021136/tomcat-starts-but-home-page-cannot-open-with-url-http-localhost8080 solved my problem. Was just a firewall clearing with iptables -F and it ran alright. Thanks

Comment: @JorgedoCarmo I have shared the same link in comments, dd you checked?

Comment: Yes, that's where I got the answer

Comment: Thanks, it did work right