# How to fix "Cannot change version of project facet Dynamic Web Module to 2.4" in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring

My WAR project was working fine but when I updated to latest version of STS (3.5.0.M2) I get the following error:

> Cannot change version of project facet Dynamic Web Module to 2.4

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot change version of project facet Dynamic Web Module to 3.0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18122336/cannot-change-version-of-project-facet-dynamic-web-module-to-3-0)

Answer (score 3):

try edit your WEB.XML file. Check on top of file

```
**http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_3_0.xsd" >**
```

Answer (score 3):

open project folder and goto .settings and open org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml change version to that matching with the one in web.xml

then Maven -> Update Project

you will observe that the error is no more:)

Answer (score 1):

open project folder and goto .settings and open org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml
change  version like this.

Answer (score 0):

This is a more detailed answer, expanding on existing ones.

### web.xml

Check your `web.xml` file.
Make sure you're using the correct XML namespace and version attributes.

Here's an example of the current version (4.0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
  version="4.0">
  <display-name>project</display-name>
  
  <!-- servlet configuration here -->
</web-app>
```

### Project Facets

The version in the `web.xhm` should match what you have in your project facets (right click your project select properties > project facets) under **Dynamic Web Module**.

[image: project facets]

### Update Maven

Right click on your project, Maven > Update Project