# eclipse contain unncessary Factory class while generating the war file

Tags: java, eclipse

I am facing new issue, since the issue is not there till yesterday now when i compiling the project, I am getting unncessary files such as servicestub$Factory.class, servicestub.class actually there is only one java file as servicestub.java file. There are no problems in the problem tab of eclipse. Earlier today i faced a problem of the .class files missing in the war file. This issue is resolve by using this link [Cannot change version of project facet Dynamic Web Module to 3.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18122336/cannot-change-version-of-project-facet-dynamic-web-module-to-3-0) but the new problem now i am getting unnecessay .class in one package and this is not there in other package. can anyone help me in sought out this problem

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure there isn't an nested class named Factory within the servicestub.java?

If you have something like

```
public class Outer {

     static class Inner {...} //or no static
...
}
```

the java compiler will create a Outer.class and a Outer$Inner.class files.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. i have inner class how can i avoid it from creating one more class while compiling

Comment: You can't. Java always creates a class file for each existing class, no matter how your code is written. Even a anonymous class will cause a Outer$1.class file... but I cannot see how this behaviour is a problem.