# Convert a web-based project into maven based project

Tags: eclipse, maven

In eclipse i've created a web project and later I convert it into maven based project by using configure.  The project is converted into maven and POM.XML is also created just i click maven update project it gives an error.

The error is:

```
Cannot change version of project facet Dynamic Web Module to 2.4.  
One or more constraints have not been specified
```

Comment: Try to manually update it in POM.xml and then do update project in Maven http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18122336/cannot-change-version-of-project-facet-dynamic-web-module-to-3-0

Comment: How can i update manually can you explain in detail

Comment: Select Maven -> Update project

Comment: I did that so many times but the error remains same.