# Eclipse imports Maven project with wrong Facets after deletion/ignore of . ide files

Tags: java, eclipse, git, maven

In a couple of our new projects, we were committing .settings, .classpath, .project into git. I recently removed all of these from the app and added them to the ignore file.

Now we have a problem, when we import the Maven project it now uses the wrong facets. It also doesn't create one of the .settings files we need.

It imports the facets including me.hibernate 4.1 instead of jpt.jpa
2.1

It also isn't creating this settings file on import any longer either: org.eclipse.jpt.core.prefs.

**UPDATE**

Interesting scenario:

With a fresh workspace..
If I clone Project A and do a maven import, it imports with the wrong settings. If I delete those settings files and remove the project from the workspace, import it again, it now imports with the correct settings.

If I now clone Project B into that workspace and maven import it, it has the correct settings files.

Now with ANOTHER new workspace I import Project B first and it has the WRONG settings files, just like Project A did. I delete those files and import project B again to the same workspace and now it has the correct settings. Now if I clone project A into that workspace and import it, it has the correct settings files.

---

So now the question is, what makes Eclipse import the project ONLY the first time?

Comment: You can try if importing them again may resolve issue.

Comment: See update @Ferrybig

Comment: Could be somehow related to http://stackoverflow.com/q/25551213/6309