# Cannot change version of project facet ear to 1.3 maven error in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jakarta-ee, wildfly-8

I am new to maven, I have created a maven project in Eclipse on Wildfly server.
Its deploying fine and working fine but I have a compilation issue in work space as like below.

> cannot change version of project facet ear to 1.3

No issue is there when i specify project facet EAR as 7.0 but in problems it is showing as in the images.

[image]

[image]

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Is your application.xml file generated by maven or have you provided a hand crafted version?

Comment: Thats not generated by maven.

Comment: This was solved for me by an answer to a different, but similar question:
[Cannot change version of project facet Dynamic Web Module to 3.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18632054/41861)

Comment: I think this question is different from the linked question that is answered. i think it is because of wrong version of  ear plugin. it should be like that: <plugin><artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId><version>2.9</version<configuration><version>7</version>...      Actually after version 1.4 of java the ear versions should be written like 5,6,7,8 and so on.

Comment: I agree with @AliReza19330!

Answer (score 3):

I hope your using Wildfly server 8 or 9, try using version (jee version) to avoid this compile error

```
<build>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.1</version>
    <configuration>
       <version>7</version>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```