# Failed to execute : org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin

Tags: maven

I creating a web project using maven, java 7, String framework, hibernate, JPA and restful service in Eclipse. I  changed the jre library in Java Build Path and also change the compiler.

but now i got error

```
Cannot change version of project facet Dynamic Web Module to 3.0.
```

thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to change the version into `web.xml` you need change some configuration you can find it below:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
    <display-name>Servlet 3.0 Web Application</display-name>
</web-app>
```

then Update Project.

Answer (score 1):

The solution given by @enkor may work for you (Question is the same):

[Cannot change version of project facet Dynamic Web Module to 3.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18122336/cannot-change-version-of-project-facet-dynamic-web-module-to-3-0/18632054#18632054)

Comment: Uh, no you cannot just post link based answers, especially if the answers are not your.