# How to prevent Maven Eclipse from making a project a Dynamic Web Module?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

There are existing questions about how to remove the Dynamic Web Module Facet from an existing project, with this one being top-ranked in Google:

- [Cannot change version of project facet Dynamic Web Module to 3.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18122336/cannot-change-version-of-project-facet-dynamic-web-module-to-3-0)

MY question is, how can I setup the `pom.xml` so that Maven does not add the Dynamic Web Module Facet to the generated Eclipse configuration to begin with?

Comment: Do you generate the project using Eclipse?

Comment: Yes, sort of. The project pre-existed outside of Eclipse and then I imported. On import, Eclipse generates whatever it needs.