# How to downgrade spring project facet to 2.4

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Am configuring a spring mvc project using a java based configuration ( no web.xml). i created the project with facet 2.4 but after maven build it is automatically upgraded to 3.1 , how do i keep project facet at 2.4 using maven ?

Comment: This might help   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18122336/cannot-change-version-of-project-facet-dynamic-web-module-to-3-0/18632054#18632054

Comment: @Ashish451 nop i tried changing through org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml and then after a maven update it was again changed to 3.1

Comment: Why do you want it on 2.4 that won't even work with a Java config that requires at least 3.0.