# How to change EJB Module Version, if ejb-jar.xml is deleted to migrate module from 2.x to 3.0

Tags: java, websphere, ejb-3.0, eclipse-wtp

[Errors on project build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucYC6.png)

Trying to migrate EJB project from 2.0 to 3.0, but got the above errors as EJB Project is referring to ejb2.0 version even Using annotations instead ejb-jar.xml in beans.

Other Details:
Server - WebSphere8.5.5 traditional server
Java - 1.8 Version

Meta-Inf of ejb module
[EJB Project Meta-INF contains](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edBb3.png)

Project Facets of  EJB project:
[EJB module version is 2.x, unable to change to 3.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GeD0S.png)
Ejb Module version in project facet is 2.0, but not allowing to change to 3.0.

Deleted ejb-jar.xml, and updated ibm bindings.
Added annotations to beans as required.

But got configurations errors. Unable to change version of ejb to 3.0.

I'm getting two ejb validation errors:

1. CHKJ2017E: This class must implement javax.ejb.SessionBean (EJB 2.0: 7.5.1, 7.10.2). ejb.jar /roject Class: com.xxxx.xxxxx.arch.app.internal.ServiceProviderBean EJB Validator Message
   2)CHKJ2017E: This interface must extend javax.ejb.EJBObject (EJB 2.0: 6.5, 7.10.5). eb.jar /Project Class: com.xxxx.xxxxx.arch.app.internal.ServiceProvider EJB Validator Message

Comment: I'd try one of the solutions form here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18122336/cannot-change-version-of-project-facet-dynamic-web-module-to-3-0 . This talks about web project but I expect similar "logic" for ejb projects. So try "uncheck", "apply", "recheck". Or just change the setting it the ...facet.core.xml file and restart Eclipse

Comment: Compilation Errors remained same, even after changing ejb version in project facets.xml

Comment: You didnt mention about any compilation errors. If you have compilation errors that completely different problem than switching spec in Eclipse, as this just changes editors in the tool not the compilation. You should put the errors in the question

Comment: 1)Description Resource Path Location Type
CHKJ2017E: This class must implement javax.ejb.SessionBean (EJB 2.0: 7.5.1, 7.10.2). ejb.jar /roject Class: com.xxxx.xxxxx.arch.app.internal.ServiceProviderBean EJB Validator Message 
2)Description Resource Path Location Type
CHKJ2017E: This interface must extend javax.ejb.EJBObject (EJB 2.0: 6.5, 7.10.5). eb.jar /Project Class: com.xxxx.xxxxx.arch.app.internal.ServiceProvider EJB Validator Message 


 I'm getting above two ejb validation errors - @Gas

Comment: Maybe your EAR is 1.4 EJB 3.0 is part of the Java EE 5 platform, so make sure you have correct EAR level, unless your EJBs are stand alone modules.